# How can I configure VSCode to lint all files in project, open or not?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've got a python project in VSCode, and I'm using the `flake8` linter and the `pyright` type checker. I'd like it to lint/check all files in the project, not just the one(s) that are open. How do I configure this?

For `pyright` there is an option "Report errors for only currently-open files." I have unchecked that. There is a similar option in python "Python -> Analysis: Open Files Only" and I've disabled that.

In both cases, I know there are errors (I can open a file and see them), but I do not see the errors in the `PROBLEMS` panel.

Is there some other way I can make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is currently not available in the Python extension, but if you would like it then please  [the relevant feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3836).

Comment: Too bad. And that issue is locked (I can't add a thumbs up as I'm not a "collaborator").

Comment: @Gordon I have unlocked the conversation so you should be able to vote for it now.

Comment: thanks! I've added a comment. Hopefully my description of the specifics is useful.

Comment: This feature request moved to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-flake8/issues/244 for `flake8`. (I don't quite understand why VSCode cannot introduce some general API, so that every single (linter) extension wouldn't have to handle this on its own...)